# "expected '}' at end of input" on arduino code

Tags: arduino-ide

I was writeing this simple arduino code and I got this error. I can clearly see that there are the appropriate brackets in place.

```
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(A7, OUTPUT);//sfx
    pinMode(A5, INPUT)pinMode(A6, OUTPUT);//flash
    ; //Button
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly
    if (digitalRead(A5) == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(A6 ,HIGH); //flash
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(A6, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(A7, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(A7, LOW);
        delay(25000);
    } else if (digitalRead(A5) == LOW); 

    {                   
        digitalWrite(A6 ,HIGH); //flash
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(A6, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(A7, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(A7, LOW);  
    }
```

I didn't know what to do to fi this issue.

Comment: `loop() {` doesn't have a closing bracket. You also shouldn't have semicolon after else if

Answer (score 1):

Despite your assurance that you have the requisite brackets, you don't.

Your `loop` function needs a closing `}`.

Employing consistent indentation is not just about making code *pretty.* It makes it easier to understand and debug. Keep in mind also that [it's always your fault.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

As noted in comments, also beware the `;` after `else if (digitalRead(A5) == LOW)`. This won't cause a compiler error, but it radically changes the behavior of your code vs. what's intended.